# Make events for Buttons?

Tags: html, button, gwt

In my HTML-file i created a Button:

```
<button class="start" id="startButton">Start</button>
```

How can i check in eclipse(in my gwt Project) if the Button is clicked? How can i adress my button in my html-file?

Normally i wrote this, when i create the button in eclipse

```
startButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() 
    {
        public void onClick (ClickEvent event) 
        {
            startProgramm();
        }
    });
```

But the startButton is not known.

Comment: Normally you create your view within your GWT applicaiton using Widgets or UiBinder. In your case, you need to explore the DOM and trying to find the button, cast the element and add an event listener. Not a usual way to do such things.

Comment: Question is, what are you trying to do?

Comment: `Button.wrap(RootPanel.get("startButton").getElement()).addClickHandler(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Usually on my applications I have different div (oder oder elements) on my HTML, where I dynamically add Widgets or elements. Let's say Sample.html has

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and the Sample class has

```
RootPanel.get("content").add(new SomeWidget());
```

SomeWidget was created using UiBinder and there you have, like in your example

```
<button ui:field="startButton" class="start">Start</button>
```

You bind the button with ui:field="startButton". In your SomeWidget class you declare

```
@UiField
HTMLButtonElement startButton;
```

and in the constructor

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", evt -> {
    startProgramm();
});
```

For the latest GWT versions and developments, I have been using the recommended elemental2 library to bind to the DOM. That's where HTMLButtonElement comes from. I've added the dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.elemental2</groupId>
    <artifactId>elemental2-dom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and added the inherited the module on Sample.gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="elemental2.dom.Dom" />
```